# How to fix cyclic inheritance involving on android interface?

Tags: java, android

I use java interface.
but occur `cyclic inheritance involving` problem.

in my situation

```
public class MainActivity extends Activty implement MainActivity.Command {

    @Override 
    protected void onCreate(final Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
       ...
    }

    public interface Command {
       void execute(String peerId, JSONObject payload) throws JSONException;
    }

    private class CreateOfferCommand implements Command {
       public void execute(String peerId, JSONObject payload) throws JSONException {
          ....
       }
    }
```

`private class CreateOfferCommand implements Command` part occur cyclic inheritance involving.

and `implement MainActivity.Command` here `must either be declared abstract or implement abstract method 'execute(String, JSONObject)' in 'Command`

message.

how to fix this problem?

thanks.

@update

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    interface Command {
        void execute(String peerId, JSONObject payload) throws JSONException;
    }

    private class CreateOfferCommand implements MainActivity.Command {
        public void execute(String peerId, JSONObject payload) throws JSONException {
        }
     }
 }
```

I try this one.
but same occur cyclic inheritance involving problem.

Comment: @DawoodibnKareem  oh ,sorry, I use implements

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is

> public class MainActivity extends Activty **implement MainActivity.Command**
>
> private class CreateOfferCommand **implements Command**

You only can `implement MainActivity.Command` for once .

You can remove `implement MainActivity.Command` in `MainActivity` .

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(final Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
}

interface Command {
    void execute(String peerId, JSONObject payload) throws JSONException;
}

class CreateOfferCommand implements MainActivity.Command {

    @Override
    public void execute(String peerId, JSONObject payload) throws JSONException {

    }
}
}
```

**Another way**

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements  MainActivity.Command{

@Override
protected void onCreate(final Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
}

@Override
public void execute(String peerId, JSONObject payload) throws JSONException {
    
}

interface Command {
    void execute(String peerId, JSONObject payload) throws JSONException;
}
}
```

**Note**

Change `Activty` to `Activity` .

Comment: I try this. remove `implements MainActivity.Command` on MainActivity and  add `Class CreateOfferCommand implements MainActivity.Command`  but same occur cyclic inheritance involving

Comment: I thought it was ok .

Comment: And it worked  in my code .So you should check for it .

Comment: And you should remove all of your code .And try my code .

Comment: ha.. I try remove all of my code, and try your code. but same error.

Answer (score 0):

You must implement the method in your interface for every class that implements it, including your Activity.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activty implements MainActivity.Command {

    // onCreate()

    @Override
    void execute(String peerId, JSONObject payload) throws JSONException {
        // You need this
    }

    public interface Command {
       void execute(String peerId, JSONObject payload) throws JSONException;
    }

    //etc
}
```

As for the Cyclic Inheritance problem, move your Command interface to its own file.

Comment: Have you tried moving your Command interface to its own file?